# How to configure Superpowered SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, superpowered

I have come across the [Superpowered SDK](http://superpowered.com/experimental-plugin-android-studio-superpowered) for processing audio in android. I am new to NDK and online there is little to no documentation about how to configure and use Superpowered, which is a shame for such a well made library.

Can someone explain me how to configure it properly?

All I did as of now is installing the NDK.

Comment: Were you able to configure superpowered to do pitch shifting and time stretching successfully?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out. I don't have much time to work on it though

Comment: Is OpenSL ES a viable alternative to SuperPowered for the same task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to start with one of the Android example projects of the Superpowered SDK. Set the 2 paths in local.properties and the project will build fine.
Also read the README, which explains these steps and even more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer the fact is that I'm completely new to NDK and reading the Android example didn't result in any benefit since I wasn't able to understand it. Is there any example specifically for pitch shifting?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Qt5 to build c++ apps for Android, using Android NDK.

This may be a helpful for some, but to include the Superpowered libs, I did this in the Project.pro file, which works.

LIBS += -lOpenSLES

LIBS += C:\Qt\Your_Project\Superpowered\libSuperpoweredAndroidarmeabi-v7a.a